# In Depth Study of today's Dharma Teachers teachings

Tags: modern-world, teaching, teachers, study

Does anyone know of any site on the internet (or elsewhere) that studies profoundly and carefully, the works of Dharma teachers? Like Mahasi Sayadaw,or Ajahn Chah, or any Dharma  teacher for that matter?

For instance, Mahasi Sayadaw's book, "The Progress of Insight" can be hard to comprehend, so what if a teacher got together with a group of students to study such a book of teachings in depth.

Perhaps something like the following:

Each pertinent sentence might be studied one by one, the translation of each sentence might be scrutinized, the scriptural origins would be analyzed and each sentence might be made better understood with real examples of what is meant.

I'm sure that sites such as these are out there but I for one have found that they can be hard to find.

I put **"today's Dharma Teachers"** in the question here not because I wanted to exclude answers about  in depth studied of older teachings. I would like to know of these in depth kind of study groups no matter how old the teacher or teachings are. I suppose I thought that if I didn't put **"today's Dharma Teachers"** that the answers would consist of the more common study of older teachings & teachers and the newer teachings & teachers might be overlooked. -Metta

Comment: Still it is not clear, if "today's Teacher" refers to living or death. As for the living ones, if they are Teacher, best to join them directly, if the heart tends to him/her.

Comment: @Samana Johann  Of course you are correct but teachers aren't always accessible. Living or deceased teachers is what was meant, respectfully.

Comment: Let us say, it would require some scarifies to meet them. Well of course such would be difficult. So what is looked for is a kind of quick on demand access?

Comment: It would be gurus on the video phone! or students of gurus.

Answer (score 4):

There are many people who are attached to Mahasi Sayadaw on [Dhammawheel](http://dhammawheel.com/) and Bhikkhu Pesala (http://aimwell.org/ or on DW) is for sure on person (since he translated much) who can help out in the sphere of his understanding.

You also can try to get in contact with Upasaka Florian. He runs a [blog](http://tsurezuregusa.de/tag/mahasi-sayadaw/) and pages on [facebook](https://www.facebook.com/fscheidemantel) and [g+](https://plus.google.com/+FlorianScheidemantel/posts) concerning much about Mahasi Sayadaw and communities around it and he had studied much. He would for sure also know other places.

As for Ajahn Chah, Atma is sure, that it would really not make sense to

> Each pertinent scentence might be studied one by one, the translation of each scentence might be scrutinized, the scriptural origins would be analyzed and each scentence might be made better understood with real examples of what is meant.

You would, in the case of Ajahn Chah, need to meet an Ajahn Chah and most would and do not like it to be confronted by him, even get mad. And you even would need to start with sweeping and other services.

Atma would also say, if not even understand an interpreter, is better to do it among the original source and get then an understanding of what the particular teaches tells.

Having read some of his books a little Atma thinks that there are less who would understand many things, if not good leaned in the scripts or have certain experiences by one self. The teachings also carry much danger of developing certain views.

The problem of not understanding the path or not coming on to it, is most seldom the teaching or the explaining, but simply the not willingness to start seriously with the home work. Dana, Sila.

> **Making Tables & Chairs**
>
> It's good to make the mind pure and at peace, but it's hard. You have
>   to start with the externals — your bodily actions and words — and work
>   your way in. The path that leads to purity, to being a contemplative,
>   is a path that can wash away greed, anger, and delusion. You have to
>   exercise restraint and self-control, which is why it's hard — but so
>   what if it's hard?
>
> It's like taking wood to make a table or make a chair. It's hard, but
>   so what if it's hard? The wood has to go through that process. Before
>   it can become a table or a chair, we have to go through the coarse and
>   heavy stages.
>
> It's the same with us. We have to become skillful where we aren't yet
>   skillful, admirable where we aren't yet admirable, competent where we
>   aren't yet competent.
>
> **Maggots**
>
> When we give rise to right view in our hearts, we can be at ease
>   wherever we are. It's because we still have wrong views, still hold
>   onto ideas that are poisonous, that we're not at ease. Holding on in
>   this way is like being a maggot. Where it lives is filthy; its food is
>   filthy. Its food isn't fit to be food — but it seems fitting to the
>   maggot. Try taking a stick and flicking it out of the excrement where
>   it's feeding, and see what happens. It'll wiggle and wriggle, eager to
>   get back to the pile of excrement where it was before. Only then does
>   it feel right.
>
> It's the same with you monks and novices. You still have wrong views.
>   Teachers come and advise you on how to have right view, but it doesn't
>   feel right to you. You keep running back to your pile of excrement.
>   Right view doesn't feel right because you're used to your old pile of
>   excrement. As long as the maggot doesn't see the filth in where it's
>   living, it can't escape. It's the same with us. As long as we don't
>   see the drawbacks of those things, we can't escape from them. They
>   make it difficult to practice.
>
> ([108 Dhamma Similes](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/thai/chah/insimpleterms_en.html))

Atma likes to add, that if you, a group, friends... would seek for an environment to do such, lessons, teaching, what ever, please feel free and invited to use the environment of this [online monastery](http://sangham.net/index.php?action=forum) and don't hesitate to ask for help or what ever in this regard. Your are free to perform it if you like to put an effort into it.

*(Note: this answer has not been given with the agreement to be means of trade or the purpose of/for trade and/or keep people trapped and bound. How you handle it lies in your sphere, but does not excuse the deed here either.)*

Comment: Well, I wrote **something like** the following: "Each pertinent scentence might be studied one by one,..." I wasn't saying things had to be like that at all. I was just giving ideas as to how it could work.

Comment: Atma is sure that you nevertheless make the best out of it. Its not meant as a demand. Being in company of those who actually practice the path is important since there is more to learn aside of words like habits and other fine things.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.acidharma.org/aci/index.html

The website link above has breakdowns of works by [Je Tsongkhapa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Je_Tsongkhapa), -- (Specifically his work on Lam Rim)
-- Nāgārjuna, Shantideva, and various lojung texts with their respective analysis.

The audio classes are MP3 streams, and the teachers tend to do a sentence by sentence breakdown of the works being discussed. 
They come with PDFs of student notes, lectures and outlines, and readings in both English and the original Tibetan.

Some sutras are also available in both languages, and the website is entirely free of any charges.